# How to change field value dynamically depended on dropdown selection in django

Tags: django, event-handling

I've been searching Google, but couldn't find a simple answer to this problem:
I have a django models that stores students information and three other models like this:

```
class Level(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Pricing(models.Model):
   level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

class Enrollment(models.Model):
   student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   date_enrolled = models.DateField()
   price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

I want the `Enrollment.price` field to be populated dynamically depending on `Enrollment.level` field value. In javascript, it amounts to setting an event listener to `Enrollement.level`, but I can't find the equivalent in django.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can modify your save method to fill automatically field ***price*** from Level model

***Enrollment.level***

```
class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_enrolled = models.DateField()
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.price = Pricing.objects.get(level=self.level).price
        super().save(*args,*kwargs)
```

but I recommend to rewrite your model like above example because its simple and you can access to price of every level directly
like ***Enrollment.level.price***

```
class Level(models.Model):
   level = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
   price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_enrolled = models.DateField()
```

I hope it helped you

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestions are very useful, but I am still wondering if it is possible to populate `Enrollment.price` dynamically. Just like a shopping cart item total price gets updated dynamically in an ecommerce app when unit price is changed.